# Fininding where a route was defined from the route name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am dealing with a Rails project that has a huge and complex list of routes. When I run `rails routes` I can see the route I want but when I look at the files that define the routes I am unable to find it. Is there any method where given the name of the route from `rails routes` it can give me a line number showing where that route was defined?

Comment: I know it is not the solution, but why is it not enough to search in the `routes.rb` file for the controller you look for? I am not aware of a command that shows you the line :(

Comment: Do you only want to see the route details or the line number also?

Comment: Which version of rails you are using?

Comment: @AsimHashmi I can see the route details from rails routes currently but I cant tell which part of the routes config has created that route. Normally just looking at routes.rb would be enough but this routing is split up over about 10 files and uses a far more complex set of features from rails routing than I have seen before.

Answer (score 1):

**For Rails <  5**

You can use

```
rails routes | grep yourSearchString
```

**For Rails >=  5**

You can use  option `-c` to search for routes related to controllers

```
rails routes -c users
```

will give you routes of  `UsersController`

You can use `-g` option to do general purpose pattern matching

```
rails routes -g users
```

will give all the routes that partially or completely matches with your search

Hope it helps :)